# render a section into a string in Razor

Tags: model-view-controller, razor

I've got some Razor code that I want to store in a string, not output to the user yet.  I figured I could put it in a @section block, then use RenderSection

```
@section mySection
{
    <div>@(model.thing1), @(model.thing2), @(model.thing3)</div>
}
@{
    //capture section into string
    string thingToCapture = RenderSection("mySection");

    //do string manipulation on code
    thingToCapture = thingToCapture.Replace("foo", "bar");

    //output string
    Html.Raw(thingToCapture);
}
```

Unfortunately RenderSection doesn't seem to return a string. It just renders it.  Is there a way to capture part of a Razor page's output in a string without making a different file and using a partial view?

Answer (score 0):

(Updated based on comments)

> For now I'm splitting it into a partial view and using Html.Partial to capture it into a string.

```
@{
    string partialViewName = "/Pages/Partials/_MyPartialView.cshtml";
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    // Partial view uses model from main Razor page if a model is
    // not passed into the partial view and the partial view
    // does not use the @model directive.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent HtmlContent =
        await Html.PartialAsync(partialViewName);
    HtmlContent.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
    string html = writer.ToString();
    html = html.Replace("foo", "bar");
}

@Html.Raw(html)
```

(Apr 14 edit)

I came across the following reference that provides a definitive statement about a section in a Razor view and why it's not accessible through code in another part of the view. It addresses why an attempt to access a section is not possible.

> Sections defined in a page or view are available only in its immediate layout page. They cannot be referenced from partials, view components, or other parts of the view system.

The quote is listed at the end of the content under the Sections subheading in this Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sections).

Comment: My example code was simple to focus on the part I'm trying to do. converting the entire section into a string manually before doing my string manipulation might be trivial in the example case, but isn't in the real code. I'm hoping to use a lot of razor syntax code then capture it into a string.  For now I'm splitting it into a partial view and using Html.Partial to capture it into a string. But I'd prefer it to be in the same file as logically it goes with the rest of the code in that file and shares the model with the main view.

Comment: Your comment adds clarification and your solution makes sense. I'll update the post to remove the content that was based on the simple example code. So that the post has some content, I'll add a code sample of the description in your comment of what you've already arrived at.